Is there a mature or officially maintained test suite for the net directory of the linux kernel source code?
The Linux protocol stack code is so large and sophisticated that there should be some way to ensure that any subsequent changes will not affect the existing functionality, but I couldn't find any test suites other than ltp (https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp), However, ltp is still a user mode test program. Is there a test suit compiled directly with the kernel source?
Any other user mode test suite or kernel test suite you know are welcome to help list them, thank you very much！

Look at tools/testing/ in kernel source, especially tools/testing/selftests/net/ . Note that these are user-space tools in the kernel source tree.

@sawdust get! thanks a lot, I only saw net/core/selftests.c before, and I was wondering why there was so little code to test at that time...
